# SQLLDR : merger year,mon and day

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have csv file that contains shown below :

```
year,mon,day
2014,12,01
2013,10,30
```

and abc's table

```
create table abc (
year varchar2(4),
mon varchar2(2),
day varchar2(2),
date1 date
)
```

how to tell loader.ctl to merger year,mon,day become date?

like that ?

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=11, errors=12000) 
LOAD DATA  
APPEND INTO TABLE abc (
year "trim (:year)",
mon "trim (:mon)",
day "trim (:day)",
date1 "to_date (year||mon||day,'yyyymmdd')"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since your fields are comma separated, you should include `fields terminated by ","` in your control file.
2. date1 is not present in the data file, but is computed. So use [EXPRESSION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1227) parameter to specify that.
3. in to_date function, use [colons](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1226) to reference the previous fields.

So, your control file should look like this,

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=11, errors=12000) 
LOAD DATA  
APPEND INTO TABLE abc
fields terminated by ","
(
year "trim (:year)",
mon "trim (:mon)",
day "trim (:day)",
date1 EXPRESSION "to_date (:year||:mon||:day,'yyyymmdd')"
)
```

Comment: refer to line `date1 EXPRESSION "to_date (:year||:mon||:day,'yyyymmdd')"`. can i use `DATE` function?

Comment: Yes, you can use to_date function.

Comment: if i want save date1 only, can i edit control file like this ?

`...
year filler,
mon filler,
day filler,
date1 EXPRESSION "to_date (:year||:mon||:day,'yyyymmdd')"
...`

Comment: I think it is not possible. I'm getting `Invalid bind variable YEAR in SQL string for column DATE1.` [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/ulus.htm)
says, `A bind variable may not refer to a filler field.`